# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null | reactjs |

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've 2 textboxes and 1 button as material UI components.

```
 </p>
        <TextField id="chatidField" />
        <br />
        <p>
          <code>Enter Your Name:</code>
          <hr />
        </p>
        <TextField id="nameField" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          onClick={addToFirebase()}
        >
          Get Your Token
        </Button>
```

the function that onClick calls is as follows:

```
  function addToFirebase() {
  var chatid = document.getElementById("chatidField").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("nameField").value;
  console.log(chatid, name);
 }
```

I keep getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
>
> 8 |   var chatid = document.getElementById("chatidField").value;
>
> 9 |   var name = document.getElementById("nameField").value;

full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/pqmrn4x

Comment: Pass function reference rather than call in onCick={addToFirebase}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your `onClick` handler, it should be `addToFirebase` not `addToFirebase()`:

```
<Button
      variant="contained"
      color="secondary"
      onClick={addToFirebase}
    >
```

When you include `()`, it will run the `addToFirebase` function, and use the return value as the `onClick` handler. In addition, if the `addToFirebase()` function is a part of your class, you will likely need to use `this.addToFirebase` instead.

Comment: @HemadriDasari They're null, because at the time that `addToFirebase()` is run, the actual DOM hasn't been rendered yet, so none of the elements with those ID's exist. After applying the onClick function correctly, when the button gets clicked, those elements should indeed exist in the DOM, and the error should go away.